# Teensy microcontroller showing slow fall time (but fast rise time)

Tags: microcontroller, teensy

My Teensy++ 2.0 is showing some slow fall times, around 1ms, when I set a pin to low (via `DigitalWrite`). It looks like there's capacitance on the line, but the rise time is pretty much zero, so that can't be it.

Has anyone had the same sort of issues? Is it possible that my Teensy is broken? I looked at the AT90USB datasheet but I couldn't find rise time and fall time on general purpose IO.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your circuit on the pin look like? How long are the lines, what are attaches to the output etc.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't toggling the tri-state enable pin? ;)

Comment: @W5VO ... you mean bit (i.e. DDRx.y)

Comment: @vicatcu Sure - whatever they call that pin on Atmel products... same concept with practically every microcontroller but everything is named differently

Comment: @W5VO yea, pin makes it sound like it's configured in the 'real world' instead of 'in software'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this happens when the DDR register is set to input instead of output.